# Make iPhone 6/6 plus resize apps automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

All my old apps are looking good on iPhone6/6+. But when I create new project iPhone 6/6+ treat apps natively. So they look awful. Instead of trying to adjust views using constraints and stuff, I decided it would be better to write app for iPhone 5 and let new iPhones scale it. I know solution is not perfect but is good enought for me. The questions is how to make new iPhones treat my app as iPhone 5 app. How to make them scale it?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't use autolayout and size classes?

Comment: too much work. I studied these constraits for days and still have little idea of how to use them

Comment: Autolayout learning process is pretty long but you will need it to develop universal apps in the future. The same happened to me. In deed, I return to learn how to use it several months later to begin to do it

Comment: Learning auto layout is absolutely essential.

Comment: well.... actually iPhone5 go out of the market soon.... Actually i think it's not worth it to spend time on autolayout...

Comment: you are wrong. YOu have to learn autolayout. You dont want to design the layout for ipad, iphone with different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a `LaunchImage` with the correct size :

```
iPhone 6                Splash screen   750 x 1334
iPhone 6 Plus landscape Splash screen   2208 x 1242
iPhone 6 Plus portrait  Splash screen   1242 x 2208
```

Comment: i have launch xib there... should i delete it?

Comment: Yes, if you delete the launch xib, it will revert to using Launch images, and if you don't provide a launch image for iPhone 6/6Plus the app will just be scaled up.

Comment: I deleted launch xib. I didn't provide any launch image but it's still not scaled...

Comment: @user1354033 You HAVE to provide lunch images if you want your app to be scaled

Comment: I did provide a lanuch image with 640x1136 size, but still it doesn't scale

Comment: yes because this is the size of the iPhone 5. see my updated answer

Comment: ok, now you got me confused. In your updated answer you wrote the sizes for iPhone6. But you said that in order to make iPhone6 treat app as iphone5, launch image should be the size of iPhone5 so 640x1136, right?

Comment: If you don't provide launchImage for iPhone 6/6plus, the default will be to scale up the app. So yes remove launch image and launch xib and just use your iPhone 5 launch image, but this is defiantly not the vest practices

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this by memory as I don't have xcode in front of me, but I'm quite sure it's correct.

You need to create and add 3 launch images to your project of the following sizes:

*640x1136
*640x960
*320x480

Go to project settings, general and select the launch image source option. Select use asset catalog, and create an asset catalog if you don't already have one.

With the asset catalog open you should have a section called launch images, if you do not, tap the '+' button in the bottom left hand corner and add the launch images option to your project. Select the launch images option.

The top row of images are used for iPhone 6/6 Plus, leave these blank. Drag and drop the launch images that you created onto the bottom two rows of images.

Return to your project settings and select the launch screen file option. Remove everything - ensure that the selection is blank. (To do this I selected my main.storyboard and just deleted the text in the text box).

And that's it, now you can automatically zoom your app on the larger devices.

Hope this helps.